# Apparently contradiction in 1Samuel 28:6 vs 1Chronicles 10:13-14

Tags: 1-samuel

Can someone explain this apparent contradiction to me?

1Sam 28:6  and Saul inquires of YHWH, and YHWH has not answered him, either by the dreams, or by the Lights, or by the prophets.

1Cr 10:13  And Saul dies because of his trespass that he trespassed against YHWH, against the word of YHWH that he did not keep, and also for asking to inquire of a familiar spirit; 14  and he did not inquire of YHWH, and He puts him to death, and turns around the kingdom to David son of Jesse. **strong text**

Answer (score 4):

The OPs version of 1 Sam. 28 is accurate enough, but we should look at 1 Chron 10:13-14 more closely. The key phrase involves the words "did not inquire of the LORD."

[image]

Translators are divided as to whether the words "did not" should be preceded by "and," "but" or "instead of/rather than." The OP presumes that "did not inquire of the LORD" means that Saul did not inquire of Him at any time, especially in 1 Sam. 28:6. However the phrase can be understood to refer only to the particular time when Saul inquired of the "familiar spirit" (also translated "ghost").  So the NABRE reads:

> Thus Saul died because of his treason against the Lord in disobeying
> his word, and also because he had sought counsel from a ghost, rather
> than from the Lord.

This translation understands Saul's sin of not consulting YHWH to relate specifically the incident with the Witch/Medium of Endor, and not to any previous attempts to call upon the LORD for advice.

In addition  to28:6, Samuel is clear that Saul did both inquire and receive an answer from the LORD on one other occasion:

1 Samuel 14:41

> 41 And Saul said to the Lord, the God of Israel: “Why did you not
> answer your servant this time? If the blame for this resides in me or
> my son Jonathan, Lord, God of Israel, respond with Urim; but if this
> guilt is in your people Israel, respond with Thummim.” Jonathan and
> Saul were designated, and the people went free. 42 Saul then said,
> “Cast lots between me and my son Jonathan.” And Jonathan was
> designated.

On yet another occasion (1 Samuel 14:37) Saul inquired of the LORD but received no answer, and as the OP mentioned there is also a general statement about the LORD not answering him in 1 Sam. 28:6.

**Conclusion**: 1 Chron. 10:14 can be understood to mean that Saul sinned specifically when he consulted the a familiar spirit *instead of* inquiring of the LORD, rather than that he never inquired of the LORD. He did in fact inquire previously several times and received an answer at least once. Because 1 Chron. does not claim that Saul never inquired of the LORD, the two verses mentioned in the OP are not contradictory.

Comment: +1. Very good answer.